# Can I direct sharing my app (which contains advertisements for Admob) to people without publish in play store?

Tags: android, admob

Can I use my app (which contains advertisements for Admob) without publishing it in Google Play Store? Can I direct sharing my app to people without publish in play store?

Will there be any problem??

Comment: Do you mean if it will be a problem with ad mob rules? Because the ads should work as usual

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem. As long as you abide by the normal AdMob policies that every publisher must, you're free to share your app how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no problem on that. Admob will serve the ads on your app.

But when you try to click on the ads by using your friends.. Your account will suspended with out any notification.